# DirectX DirectInput C# measure audio input

Tags: c#, directx, directinput

C# 2008 SP3

I have developed a softphone and our client would like to have a feature that would test if the microphone is working.

I was thinking to have a progress bar that would go up and down based on the nose level.

I have done a bit of research on this. But I couldn't find any tutorials on directX DirectInput what would help me measure the audio input. Does anyone know of any websites where this has been done before?

I am new to programming in direct x. Do I have to download the DirectX sdk?

Many thanks,

Comment: How did you develop a softphone without using audio input?

Comment: Hello, The sip library we are using have the audio input. However, it can't test if the microphone is working. I wasn't sure about the DirectInput, I was just guessing. I will take a look at the directSound. Any good tutorials out there?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout it may help.
[NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) based [Voice recorder](http://voicerecorder.codeplex.com/)